# UITabBarController not changing the title color after setSelectedIndex

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Actually, the problem is in the question title. The thing is that I need to change the active tab of a UITabBarController in my application. I do it by following:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]; //2 is just for instance
```

The strange thing about it is that it really changes the selected tab but still the title color of this tab stays the same (gray) and I want it to become white just as if I tapped on the tab. Do you have any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the code which sets the initial state of the tabbar:

```
UITabBarController *mvc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

AccountManagmentViewController *accountvc = [[AccountManagmentViewController alloc]init];
ListTableViewController *ltvc = [[ListTableViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *listNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ltvc];


CalendarViewController *calendarvc = [[CalendarViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *calendarNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:calendarvc];


ListsManagerViewController  *listsManager = [[ListsManagerViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *listsNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listsManager];

SettingsViewController *settings = [[SettingsViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *settingsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:settings];

[accountvc.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarUserIconImageActive:YES] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[EasyUITheme  currentTheme]tabBarUserIconImageActive:NO]];

[listsNavcon.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarListsIconImageActive:YES] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarListsIconImageActive:NO]];
[calendarNavcon.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarCalendarIconImageActive:YES] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarCalendarIconImageActive:NO]];
[listNavcon.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarMain10IconImageActive:YES] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarMain10IconImageActive:NO]];
[settings.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarSettingsIconImageActive:YES] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarSettingsIconImageActive:NO]];
[accountvc.tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Account", nil)];
[listsNavcon.tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Lists", nil)];
[calendarNavcon.tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Calendar", nil)];
[listNavcon.tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Words", nil)];
[settings.tabBarItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil)];
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing But in my case it is changing the color of the title So Can you show the code of tabbar title setting?

Comment: I've added it, but I guess there's nothing unusual about it. The `[[EasyUITheme currentTheme]tabBarListsIconImageActive:YES]` just returns UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

```
AccountManagmentViewController *accountvc = [AccountManagmentViewController instanceOfNibNamed:@"AccountManagmentViewController"];
UINavigationController *accountvcNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:accountvc];
accountvcNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
UITabBarItem* accountTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
[accountTabBarItem setTitle:@"Account"];
[accountTabBarItem  setFinishedSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3"]
                        withFinishedUnselectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"tab3"]];
[accountvcNavigationController setTabBarItem: accountTabBarItem];
[viewControllers addObject:accountvcNavigationController];
```

Try like this. It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing an `UITabBarController` delegate. It has a method similar to the `didSelect: method` offered by

```
UITabBar delegate:
tabBarController:didSelectViewController:
```

. It will be called after the user has selected another tab.

See: [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol Reference